# Identify this person with 13 clues given

Tags: riddle, knowledge

I was given riddle and have not been able to solve. Can anyone help me please?

1. I'm an executive producer.
2. I love gold shoes.
3. I was born in Kansas.
4. I'm well traveled.
5. I'm a designer. (not clothing)
6. I have "Happy Feet".
7. I'm a natural blonde.
8. I've been on TV.
9. My middle name is Joyce.
10. I was born in the early 40's.
11. It's a Female
12. She has a show geared towards a specific genre.
13. She has videos on You Tube.

Who am I?

Comment: Haven't got a whole answer yet, but the vast range of all these suggests an actor, with the clues each representing a role

Comment: I had assumed the same  - thought I had it solved twice but the middle name wasn't Joyce. I appreciate you trying to help me solve.

Comment: @karin Is it a personality or a company?

Comment: These were the only clues given but # 7 makes me think personality

Comment: This feels like the trivia tag should be applied.

Comment: Thanks or the suggestion Ian MacDonald -- I just added

Comment: Been doing all kinds of research and reading and just can't figure it out

Comment: I was given a few more clues just now so wanted to share. It is a real person and SHE has a show geared towards a specific genre. Also she has videos on YouTube

Comment: Who gave you this puzzle ? Where was it given ? I ask because these may likely contain contextual assumptions & implied clues.

Comment: Do you know if she's alive?

Comment: @ Raystafarian -- Yes I believe she is alive as it was presented to me

Comment: @Prem - I was asked this by a friend that has been working on this the past week and was unable to solve. I am not sure how he came to it. He is at work now but I can find out in a few hours when he gets off.

Comment: I've been searching for producer born in 1940,1941,1942,1943 in  [imdb](http://www.imdb.com/search/name?birth_year=1940&gender=female&sort=starmeter,asc&start=1) and i haven't found one who have 2 of the statements

Comment: @TroyAndAbed - I have been on that website the last 45 minutes and I am still searching as well.

Comment: Elaine Joyce Pinochet? // http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0431519/bio?ref_=nm_ov_bio_sm // https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elaine_Joyce

Answer (score 2):

Okay, I think I might be onto something, but I haven't dug up answers to all the clues. I think @LogicianWithAHat was on the right track with different clues representing different roles. Here's what I have so far:

**My answer:**

> Amy Adams

**The clues (most are "[role] in [movie]"):**

I'm an executive producer.

> I forgot which role I had here

I love gold shoes.

> Sydney Prosser in *American Hustle*

I was born in Kansas.

> Lois Lane in *Man of Steel*

I'm well traveled.

> Amelia Earhart in *Night at the Museum: Battle of the Smithsonian*

I'm a designer. (not clothing)

> Amy in *Her* (she's a video game designer)

I have "Happy Feet".

> Perhaps Giselle in *Enchanted*? She does a lot of dancing.

I'm a natural blonde.

> Not sure

I've been on TV.

> She's been on multiple TV shows, including *The Office* and, interestingly, *Smallville*

My middle name is Joyce.

> Not sure, trying to find a character she played with this last name.

I was born in the early 40's.

> Janis Joplin in an upcoming biopic (Janis Joplin was born in 1943)

It's a Female

> Check

She has a show geared towards a specific genre.

> Not sure

She has videos on You Tube.

> She does, but so do many celebrities.

So many of the roles fit that I think I'm probably right, but I'm having trouble filling in all the holes. I thought I'd figured out the executive producer clue, but I can't remember which role it was. Additional thoughts are welcome!

[Here's her imdb if you want to go a-searching.](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0010736/)

Comment: @ VictorHenry -- I am going to do some research on her as well and I Thank You for the time/effort you put in. I had not thought to go in that direction but it seems logical now seeing it

Comment: It'll be weird (and confusing) if some clues points toward her roles and some others towards herself.

Comment: @TroyAndAbed Yeah, I totally agree. The Gold Shoes, Kansas, Well-Traveled, and Designer clues fit so well though, I'm probably too stuck on her.

Comment: @VictorHenry Done some searching, and found this. ' ...her hair is **naturally** more of a **blonde** / strawberry blonde color... '

Comment: It is not here -- I texted him and he said that she was mentioned by another in his group and it was confirmed it is not Amy Adams

Comment: Darn it -- back to square one but i do like how you came up with that and pieced it all together,

Answer (score 1):

Okay, new theory!

> Elizabeth Banks

[IMDB](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0006969/)

Clues that fit so far:

Executive Producer

> Elizabeth Banks has 3 executive producer credits

Gold shoes

> Effie Trinket in *Hunger Games* https://www.pinterest.com/pin/188869778093095188/

Kansas

> Perhaps her debut, Vicki in *Surrender **Dorothy***?

TV show in a "specific genre"

> Wet Hot American Summer, currently running

Youtube

> Has a youtube series called "Ask A Badass"

Still working on the others, but the TV Show and Youtube clues fit way better here than for my other answer.

Comment: I just texted him to ask if it is a person portraying many characters to see if we (you) are in the right line of thinking. I will let you know when I hear back